# Reporte ASP.NET C# Datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, reportviewer

necesito crear un reporte que sea alimentado con un datatable.

Actualmente mi proyecto muestra una grid de balance general que se alimenta desde un public static datatable que se trabajó en una clase en el código behind de C#.

Éste datatable ó tabla contiene los datos ya formateados, o sea el orden apropiado e interlineado necesarios con el nombre del insciso, las trae como que si las hubiera hecho en excel (sin colores ni negrita ni nada de eso claro está, solo el interlineado me refiero). Es por ende que no se me quita la idea que sería maravilloso encontrar un componente en el reporte como: un table grid que yo pueda alimentar con éste datatable estático de C# porque no tendría que preocuparme de nada más que por las negritas.

No sé si es posible, o estoy en un error.

Al final que si consulto nuevamente la base de datos tendría otra vez que tomar el tiempo para crear las lineas una por una porque todas difieren. y tendría que volver a consultar a la BD.

Ej.

Balance general:

Activos circulantes       #
1-                        #
2-                        #
3-                        #
Activos no circulantes    #
1-                        #
2-                        #
3-                        #
4-                        #
Total Activos             #

Y así sucesivamente hasta terminar la lista.

La cosulta inicial que está en un método de la applicación solo consulta algunos cambos de la BD y muchos otros son calculados con formulas apra así formar la tabla oficial.

adjunto el modelo de estructura que se desea. Espero no haya confundido.

[Excel Aquí](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AnDRQVW_baNThz6NjFxYNKVXTfuj)

Ojo, el reporte no es exportarlo a excel, debería ser en un report viewer y luego imprimirlo.

Answer (score 1):

Buenas, te presento la librería [kendo](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid), con ella haces automáticamente una tabla de una forma muy sencilla, viene muy bien explicado en la web.

Aqui te dejo un ejemplo de utilización, cualquier duda puedes preguntarme:

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/index

Con el `datasource` podrías tratar la información como quisieras, si quieres que sea más exacto, por favor, muestra más código y te diré como montarla, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Justamente para poder darle formato al reporte no tenes que usar el elemento dataGridView, tenes que usar el ReportViewer

Te dejo un vídeo para que te guies como usarlo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G1OuPZNsCr4 a partir del 6.30 te explica la parte de la vista, antes hace la vinculacion con la base